# Missing Organization Feature: DataDotComClean Error While Installing an App

Tags: administration, error, app

I have one app (Private) published. and When I try to install i get this error message. Any suggestions, I have passed Appexchange Review, Did I miss something in my Managed Package ??

Answer (score 3):

The same problem was reported here [Missing Organization Feature: DataDotComClean, i dont even have data.com enabled](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gke3AAA).

When you upload your package (you can start the process but not finish it to check the current setting) check that your package does not have the "Required" checkbox checked for "Data.com Clean":

[image: package requirements]

This might have been checked accidentally or more likely some reference in your package is causing it to be automatically checked and you need to track down and remove that reference. (Or make "Data.com Clean" a pre-requisite for your package.)

Comment: Ohhk, I got the problem I have kept Data.Com Clean Checked, Now What ? I am done with all reviews and I was about to publish that app publicly. I see that I cant edit the changes now. Now what should I have to do.

Comment: and How come this was working good when I was using URL Links  of Package Upload to install it ?

Comment: @NileshMendhe You'll have to remove the dependency (AFAIK you should be able to but I may be wrong) and upload another version. I think e.g. for the security review you will be able to just ask and get an approval as its not a relevant change. But it might take a day or two.

Comment: @NileshMendhe If the org you are installing into has the feature there won't be a problem; perhaps that explains why you get varied results?

Comment: I tried to create another package but it shows Data.com Clean selected automatically, which I cant edit too. with following message on top....   Administrators will not be allowed to install this package if their salesforce.com configuration does not meet the requirements specified (some requirements have been automatically detected as part of the sharing process).

Comment: @NileshMendhe Are you sure that you don't reference something related to Data.com that in your code? Do you have it turned on in the org you are doing the packaging?

Comment: While creating my First Package (Unmanaged,Managed & Release) I kept it on (I dont know how, It was mistake). AND My Code has nothing to do with Data.com clean, I am just getting selected records from the List view on one VF page and performing and Update/Delete operations on it. AND When I found (unable to Install after review Pass),I Disabled Data.Com Clean from the Source Org, then created an another Unmanaged Package and trying to upload it, so that I can send these new package as release package for AppExchange Review Again.